# What is the chance of me getting PHD scholarship for international student in Australia

Tags: phd

So I'm an international student in Australia. I got a lower second class bachelor of mechanical engineering (honours) from Curtin University. My final year research thesis was published in Journal of Materials Research and Technology on ScienceDirect (Elsevier).

Is it possible for me to get a PHD scholarship in Australia ? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. I realize the "duplicate" question is about the US, whereas you are in Australia. But the top part of the top answer still applies -- there is no formula to calculate your odds of admission, and this site does not offer individualized assessments. Sorry we can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You only know if you apply.   It all depends on the applicants applying to a university in a given round.  If everyone has a high GPA and top quality publications, then your chance is probably zero.  Further, given the current pandemic climate, universities may have more (or fewer) scholarships.